# discord bot isn't moving people when they deafen

Tags: discord.js

Basically, I'm trying to get my bot to move people to afk as soon as they deafen but nothing happens when I test it. I have used console.log when someone deafens but still nothing.

code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_VOICE_STATES", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_PRESENCES"] });



client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) =>
{


    let memchange = newState.member;
    if (memchange.selfDeaf)
    {
        console.log('User has deafened');
        memchange.setChannel(afkchannelid);
    }
});



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Discord bot is now online')
    
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally thought that your question may have been a simple intents issue, however, upon further investigation it is an issue regarding your use of `newState.member.selfDeaf`. The corrected code is below with a short explanation:

Taking a look at the official Discord.js Documntation regarding [`voiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/VoiceState):

From what you're doing, you're attempting to access `newState.member.selfDeaf`, whereas the `newState.member` does not have a `selfDeaf` property ([GuildMember Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMember)); thus the if statement will not evaluate as true and will not run.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES", "GUILD_VOICE_STATES", "GUILD_MEMBERS", "GUILD_PRESENCES"] });



client.on("voiceStateUpdate", (oldState, newState) =>
{
    if (newState.selfDeaf)
    {
        console.log('User has deafened');
        newState.member.setChannel(afkchannelid);
    }
});



client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Discord bot is now online')
});
```